# How to classify a group of order $15$ with Sylow theorems?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to classify a group of order $15$ with Sylow theorems?

Is it simple?

Answer:

$15=3 \times 5$

$Sylow-3$ subgroup of order $3$ is equal to $n_3=3k+1, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}.$

For $k=0$, $ \ n_3=1|15$,

For $k=1$, $ \ n_3=7 $ does not divide $15$.

Thus only one sylow$-3$ subgroup of order $3$.

Hence it is normal.

This shows the group is not simple.

Am I right?

Comment: For $k=1$, we get $n_3=4$.

Comment: ok, but you ca say more, try to do the same analysis on the $5$- subgroup of sylow and eventually that $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5$

Comment: @ALG, please vote my question because i am new and I need some points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlights:

1. What you did so far is fine, check your arithmetic: $\;k=1\implies n_3=4\;$ , but we get the same conclusion
2. With the prime $\;5\;$ you shall get a very similar conclusion as with $\;3\;$ .
3. You thus have two *normal* subgroups $\;P_3,\,P_5\;$ of order $\;3,5\;$ resp., so you can already conclude that $\;G=P_3P_5\;$ .
4. Finally, if you've already studied direct products, the above (and a very little more...)  in fact means $\;G\cong P_3\times P_5\;\cong C_{15}=\;$ the cyclic group of order $\;15\;$ .

Fill in details.